# Touch gestures in WinRT (using monogame)

Tags: c#, xna, windows-runtime, monogame

I currently have the following code:

```
internal void HandleTouch()
{
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.DragComplete | GestureType.FreeDrag;

    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.DragComplete)
        {
            MyAction(gesture.Delta.X, gesture.Delta.Y);
        }
        else if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)
        {
            OtherAction();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that the `Delta` is always 0.  I read somewhere that Monogame deals with dragging gestures differently, but whether I use this method, or manually iterate through the touch collection, I get the same issue.

How can I change this so that I get the correct delta value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing using

```
TouchCollection touches = TouchPanel.GetState();
```

and then the first time you detect a touch

```
touches.First().State == TouchLocationState.Pressed || touches.First().State == TouchLocationState.Moved
```

you save the location `touches.First().Position`

Then to detect when the drag is over

```
touches.First().State == TouchLocationState.Released
```

you can compute the `Delta` using `Vector2.Distance`