# Detecting multiple gestures in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, gesture, monogame

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281147/touch-gestures-in-winrt-using-monogame) question some time ago, concerning detecting drag gestures in XNA.  The answer for that worked well, and I used the same method to detect both drag and tap.  However, now I want to detect a third gesture of double tap.  I tried a number of methods for this, but I can't seem to get the code using the `TouchCollection` to detect double tap, because I'm effectively trying to detect a first and second gesture after the drag.  Here's the code the I was working with for the tap and drag:

```
foreach (TouchLocation touch in touchCollection)
{                
    switch (touch.State)
    {
        case TouchLocationState.Pressed:
            if (CheckTouchLocation(touch.Position))
            {
                 dragStart = touch;                        
            }
            else
            {
                 dragStart = null;
            }
            break;
       case TouchLocationState.Released:
            DragRelease(touch); // Happens before I can detect double tap
            break;
       default:
            continue;
```

As I result, I reverted to the initial way of doing it, as this seems to support double tap by default:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures =
    GestureType.FreeDrag | GestureType.DragComplete | GestureType.DoubleTap | GestureType.Tap;

while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
    switch (gs.GestureType)
    {
        case GestureType.DragComplete:                    
            if (gs.Delta.LengthSquared() > DRAG_TOLERANCE)
            {
                if (gs.Delta.X != 0 || gs.Delta.Y != 0)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
            break;

        case GestureType.Tap:
            // Do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

This appears to now be a different issue; if I detect `freedrag` then I get the event before I release; when I detect `release` as above, I don't get any event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dealing with this by using a boolean variable to store whether the user had double tapped, and delaying the tap gesture by 100ms:

```
Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith((args) =>
{
    if (!dblTap)
```

I blogged about it [here](http://pmichaelsdev.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/detecting-multiple-gesture-types-using-monogame-in-windows-8/).